# How do I link the environment variable PACKAGE_DIRS to my local, private packages?

Tags: terminal, meteor, environment-variables

I'm trying to set up an environment variable so that when I'm working on a meteor application, and I want to link a local, private package to my project, meteor will look in a packages directory that I created on my local environment.

The first thing I did was to create a packages directory and add a basic test package to it

```
/Users/scotty/Documents/web_apps/meteor_apps/packages/my-package
```

Then I opened up the terminal and typed:

```
nano ~/.bashrc
```

Once inside my bashrc file, I added the following export line:

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
export PACKAGE_DIRS="/Users/scotty/Documents/web_apps/meteor_apps/packages"
```

Note: The top PATH line was already there.

I then cd into a test meteor project called "test_packages" and tried to install my test package: "my-package" using the following command:

```
meteor add my-package
```

and got an error: no such package

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my particular case and according to [this post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/42537/why-must-i-source-bashrc-every-time-i-open-terminal-for-aliases-to-work), when starting up the terminal, by default "login shell" is started, and bash does not use .bashrc for login shells.

My solution was to do the following:

1. open the bashrc file in an editor from the terminal (I used nano): `nano ~/.bashrc`
2. add the environment variable to the file:

   `export PACKAGE_DIRS="/Users/path/to/your/packages"`

   for me this looked like:

   `export PACKAGE_DIRS="/Users/scotty/Documents/web_apps/meteor_apps/packages"`

   [image]
3. if using nano, hit ctrl + x and then hit enter so save and exit
4. open up ~/.bash_profile: `nano ~/.bash_profile`
5. add the following: `[[ -s ~/.bashrc ]] && source ~/.bashrc`

   Note: this will load the ~/.bashrc file

   [image]
6. hit ctrl + x and then enter
7. quite the terminal
8. reopen the terminal and type the command: `source ~/.bashrc`

From there, you should be able to cd into your meteor application and run `meteor add local-package-name`. Meteor will look in your local packages directory and add the package if all went well.

Comment: Could we use local package and atmostphere package at the same time?