# Automatically add Meteor packages when putting them in the packages-Directory

Tags: mongodb, meteor, meteorite

I'm currently developing a Meteor application where I want to auto-Add packages with a special .json-File in it to Meteor when dropping them in the packages-Folder. Those packages are also stored in a MongoDB collection because they get displayed on a page in the meteor-App.

I'm doing the following to accomplish that.

1. Iterate over the package-Collection in the database and run "meteor remove package-name" for each package in the collection
2. Search for all the "special"-Packages by looking in the folders for the .json-File and store them in an array
3. Iterate over the array and store the package (with its name and so on) in the database-Collection
4. Add the package to Meteor by running "meteor add package-name" for each package in the array

Everything works great so far. Except for one thing.
The Meteor app will restart the server if the package-File changes. And my approach above will yield to an infinite-loop (because the remove and add-Functionality will trigger Meteor to restart the server again).

Is there another approach to accomplish such a behavior? Am I missing something.

I'm just trying to rebuild the mechanism where Meteor automatically added all the packages in the packages-Directory without the need to run "meteor add" for each package (I think this has changed with Version 0.6.5).

Comment: Basically, you should have another copy of your meteor meteor project for doing builds.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be exactly what you want, but the [`PACKAGE_DIRS` environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18290516/586086) will cause Meteor to automatically search for packages in a specific directory, so you can just `meteor add` the packages you want without having to drop them all in the packages directory for that app.

On a related note, you don't need to add the package names to a collection, because they are available in the `Package` global variable on the client and the server.